# Wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

Tags: c++, templates

I am making a class calculator using templates, I have defined two template classes T and T1, and below I only want to pass one of the template type.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
template <class T,class T1>

class cal{
    protected:
    T val;
    
    public:
        cal(T val){
            this->val=val;
            cout<<"Data type is "<<typeid(val).name()<<endl;
//          cout<<val;
        }
//      template<class T1>
        cal(const cal<T>& a){
            this->val=a.val;
            }
            
        void operator = (const cal<T1>& a){
            this->val=a.val;
            cout<<"Value has been Assigned: "<<val<<endl; 
        }
        
};
int main(){
    cal<int> x(10);
    cal<float> y;
    y=x;
}
```

While I compile this program it gives an error "Wrong number of template arguments"

```
29  9   D:\dev c++\projects\CT-22036_A2_Q1.cpp  [Error] wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

Comment: Well, it is what it says on the tin. Class template `cal` is defined to take two template parameters, but you are trying to instantiate it with one.

Comment: If you are dealing with only int and float, you don't need two template arguments based on what you seem to be trying to do. Also, in the assignment sign overloading, if T1 is float and T is int, then your compiler should give a warning of a possible loss of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely wanted to make the assignment operator a template and its template parameter not a class template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class cal{
protected:
    T val;

public:
    cal(T val) : val(val) {
        cout<<"Data type is "<<typeid(val).name()<<endl;
    }
    cal(const cal<T>& a) : val(a.val) {}
        
    template <class T1>
    void operator = (const cal<T1>& a){
        this->val=a.val;
        cout<<"Value has been Assigned: "<<val<<endl; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Now the Error is 
22 16 D:\dev c++\projects\CT-22036_A2_Q1.cpp [Error] 'int cal<int>::val' is protected within this context

Comment: @Qartzai `val` needs to be in public